# How can i create a google maps URL that will bring up a map of somebodies current location, and bring them to a specific address?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova, google-maps-api-2

For example, http://maps.google.com/maps?q=to+chicago&hl=en&sll=40.680638,-89.846191&sspn=4.715299,9.865723&vpsrc=0&t=h&z=10 will bring you from your location to Chicago, although im not sure how the geocoding works. This is going in an iPhone app where the person will need specific directions from where they are, to a given location. Its web app based, so if it works on the computer, it will work on the phone.

Comment: May i suggest this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282369/opening-native-google-maps-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

enternet is full of open source projects you looking. for example: https://github.com/route-me/route-me

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a script that can put the address at the end of a maps.google.com query url.

maps.google.com query url's look like this http://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.0625,-95.677068

you can places whatever you want in the query ex: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=los+angeles