# mobile site, click google map to open native google map app

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, google-maps

I need to make a google map, upon click or press, open up the native app on the mobile device to show maps, passing the lat lng of the pin.

I have looked around and figured someone must've done this before.  I need this to work for iPhone and Android.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642481/android-launch-google-map-via-web-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wanna check the following links:

**-For iOS:**

- [Opening native google maps in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282369/opening-native-google-maps-in-xcode)

**-For Android:**

- [Android - launch google map via web url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642481/android-launch-google-map-via-web-url)

Hope this helps.